# Is there any other way to set route-regex, apart from file-names?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm currently hitting a limitation with routing in sapper. We need to create a route that matches two "slugs", like this `[section(foo|bar)]`. This works fine on *nix, but fails on Windows, due to the illegal `|` character.
Next to this route, there's also a `[slug]` route on the same level, that matches all the rest. This is on purpose, as only `foo` and `bar` should render differently and they will also have sub-routes.

I thought about the following approaches:

- Handle everything in the `[slug]` route, by checking if `slug` is either `foo` or `bar` and treating these cases differently. *I'd rather not do this because code will get hard to read/maintain and there are sub-routes that should only apply to `foo` and `bar`*
- Create two folders `foo` and `bar`, instead of one named `[section(foo|bar)]`. *This is undesirable, because it would mean lots of duplicated code*
- Prefix the route, eg. create a folder `section`, that contains a `[slug]` route. This seems like the least problematic option, but I'd prefer `/foo` as URL instead of `/section/foo`.

Is there any other possible option? Maybe a Windows compatible way of writing `[section(foo|bar)]`? Or a way to define routing RegEx, other than via filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well, I only have an idea for you. and buyer beware...  though I've tried; I've yet to get the basics of the following concept working in my project and ended up coming to the same [foo][bar] solution.*

Sapper has a concept called ***spread routes***.  They are denoted using the `[...slug].svelte` file/router convention.

The idea is that using the `...spread` operator in the filename informs the router that this param should be treated as an ***array of objects*** capable of holding elements.  The router is supposed to `.join('/')` all of the array elements to form the route...

- *from the Sapper docs*

  > If you don't want to create several folders to capture more than one parameter like `[year]/[month]/...`, or if the number of parameters is dynamic, you can use a spread route parameter. For example, instead of individually capturing `/blog/[slug]/[year]/[month]/[day]`, you can create a file for `/blog/[...slug].svelte` and extract the params like so:

```js
<!-- src/routes/blog/[...slug].svelte -->
<script context="module">
    export async function preload({ params }) {
        let [slug, year, month, day] = params.slug;

        return { slug, year, month, day };
    }
</script>
```

The idea I have for you is to leverage spread routing so you bypass the pipe `|` character problem by shimming your query in as one of those objects.

Comment: Sorry for never accepting your answer. This really is the best solution, but thankfully obsolete with SvelteKit.